# comparison of domains of unbounded operators with complex powers

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

Let $\cal H$ be a Hilbert space and $T$ be a non-negative invertible self-adjoint (unbounded) operator on $\cal H$. Let $\lambda >0$, and consider $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $z=\alpha-i\beta$, with $0\le \beta \le \lambda$. Now consider the operators $T^\lambda,~T^{iz}$ and $T^{\beta}$. Now I want to show that $D(T^\lambda) \subset D(T^\beta)$ and $D(T^\beta)=D(T^{iz})$, where $D(A)$ denotes the domain of definition of the operator $A$ on $\cal H$.
So, since $T$ is non-negative we can define using continuous functional calculus $T^\lambda$ and $T^\beta$ easily as $\lambda,\beta >0$. Now note that $iz=i(\alpha-i\beta)=\beta-i\alpha$. Now I am unable to understand how to define $T^{\beta-i\alpha}$ and also their domain of definitions.

Basically I know that for the unbounded operators domain plays an important role. I started unbounded operator and the aforementioned argument was given in a lecture. I am unable to understand how the operator $T^{iz}$ is defined and how can I understand domains of $T^\lambda,~T^{iz}$ and $T^{\beta}$ and the relation given above between their domains?
Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Since $T$ is invertible, $0\not\in\operatorname{sp}(T)$, so that $\operatorname{sp}(T)\subseteq [a,+\infty)$ for some $a>0$.  The function $x^{i\alpha}$ is well-defined and continuous on such a domain for any $\alpha\in\Bbb{R}$ by $x^{i\alpha} = \exp(i\alpha\log x)$ using the real-valued $\log$.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thank you John. It is helpful. But can you help me to understand how to compare their domains?

Comment: $x^{i\alpha}$ maps into the unit circle $\{z:|z|<1\}$, so mutiplying by $T^{i\alpha}$ shouldn't have to change the domain.  It's a unitary operator that leaves $D(T)$ invariant.